# How to refresh mkannotations in map view satisfactorily?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I was thinking in which is the best way to refresh (add and/or remove them) my Annotations in MapView. Now I always refresh them when regionDidChangeAnimated is called, but I know that it is not a good thing to do because this refresh calls an webservice to get all annotations' coordinate in a database, but it costs  too much (money for 3G connections and time too).

Do you have any suggestion to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Load all the annotation coordinates from your remote database into a local Core Data database, and use local queries to refresh your annotations

Comment: but they r thousands (and it will increase)... Do u think that it is the best solution?
I just show between 20-50 random annotations on screen.

Comment: Yes, Core Data is very efficient.  Make sure to set INDEXes on your coordinates so that the query is most efficient.  The tricky part will be keeping the local DB synchronized with the server ... i.e. detecting and refreshing "dirty" records

Comment: My records don't change, they just increase. BTW I just need data from a recent past (1-2 days)... so I have to refresh this data (core data) every time that the App starts and when a contribution occurs. I don't know but I think that it is more complex, don't u think?

How can I check for a update on my database (remote)? Will I check every 5 mim and actualize my core data? Maybe this is more expensive than the first solution.